# Can't Add id property to a view in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working on a project using Sencha Touch 2.

anytime i add the property "id" to the my view the whole application stops working

like if i add this

```
id: myapp.views.RoadNotifier,
```

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: what is the value of `myapp.views.RoadNotifier`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign string value instead of object.

For example:

```
id: "myapp.views.RoadNotifier", // good!
id: myapp.views.RoadNotifier, // bad!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` ***must never*** be specified like a full clasified name of the view file.

That should come as your name inside `Ext.define(` code.

Look at the below code. You should name it similarly for your application.

```
Ext.define('myapp.views.RoadNotifier', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'roadNotifier',
    id: 'roadNotifierId',
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

use 
`id:"RoadNotifier"`,
this will work